# What is the difference between a line segment inside and outside of a concave polygon?

Tags: python, graph, geometry, polygon, concave

My question is about the creation of visibility graphs in surfaces with multiple convex and concave polygons. My problem is that i am not able to classify whether the line segments connecting the nodes of the same polygon go through or don't go through this polygon. As seen in the picture below:

[image: example]

I'd need to separate the orange, invalid lines from the blue, valid lines. I hope somebody can provide me a solution to this problem with a suitable algorithm that can be implemented in python.

Or for even complexer polygons?:
[difficult polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMXPp.png)

Comment: In which form do you have the polygon?The coordinates of vertices?

Comment: Exactly! I have the coordinates of all vertices.

Comment: Do you know which pairs of points (edges) conforms the boundary of the non-convex polygon?

Comment: No, there's no more information than the vertices.

Comment: If you only have the vertex locations you don't really have *a* polygon.  Given the vertices in the polygon shown above it's relatively straightforward to draw 2 or 3 different polygons.  Which kind of makes 'insideness' tests difficult to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: this image explains the three cases]This code accepts A and B as two vertices and checks if the line joining them lies completely inside , partially inside or completely outside the polygon. This is based on mathematical fact that for a line with eqn. F(X,y):Ax+By+C the point x1,y1 will lie on the line if F(x1,y1)=0
On one side of line if F(x1,y1)>0
On other side of line if F(x1,y1)<0

```
L=[] #list of all the vertices of the polygon as (x,y) tuples in order
A=() 
B=()
# A and B are tuples of coordinates of points joking diagonal to check
def eqn(A,B):
    X1=A[0];Y1=A[1]
    X2=B[0];Y2=B[1]
return(X2-X1,Y1-Y2,X1*Y2-X2*Y1)
def check(Y,X,C,y,x):
    if(Y*y+X*X+C>0):
          return 1
    elif(Y*y+X*X+C<0):
          return -1
    else:
          return 0

Y,X,C=eqn(A,B)
#get parameters of diagonal joining A and B
a=L.index(A)
b=L.index(B)
L1=[]
L2=[]
if(a>b):
     L1=L[b+1:a]
     L2=L[a+1:]+L[:b]
elif(b>a):
     L1=L[a+1:b]
     L2=L[b+1:]+L[:a]
#so I have split the list into two lists L1 and L2 containing vertices in cyclic order on either side of the diagonal
k=1
m=0
val1=check(Y,X,C,L1[0][1],L1[0][0])
val2=check(Y,X,C,L2[0][1],L2[0][0])
if(val1==val2):
    k=0
    m=1
else:
# I have to check F(x,y) for each point in list L1 and L2 it should be of one sign for all elements in L1 and of other sign for all elements in L2 for line to lie completely inside polygon
    for t in L1:
        if(check(Y,X,C,t[1],t[0])!=val1):
          k=0
          m=0
    for s in L2:
        if(check(Y,X,C,s[1],s[0])!=val2):
           k=0
           m=0
if(k==0):
     print('the diagonal passes outside')
else:
     print('the diagonal lies completely inside the polygon')
if(m==1):
     print('the diagonal lies completely outside the polygon')
```

I have written the code hope it works as required,but there maybe errors:o,the logic is correct,there may be syntax or other errors you have to take care of(I can help in that case)  I have excluded one case if the two points chosen are consecutive,then it is obviously the side of the polygon(trivial to check).

Comment: Hello, thank you for providing a solution but I get a list index out of range error in either line 32 or line 33 depending on my A and B. For which python version is this code?

Comment: The code is for python3. Please provide the line. Is the error only for some values of A and B

Comment: These are the two lines:                                                       
val1=check(Y,X,C,L1[0][1],L1[0][0])
val2=check(Y,X,C,L2[0][1],L2[0][0])

Comment: And could you please the concept a bit more because i didn't understand it 100%

Comment: So we draw a diagonal. The diagonal divides the vertices of polygon into two groups (lists L1 and L2). Each on either side of the diagonal(I have excluded the points on the diagonal A and B). So then I check for each point in the lists. If each point in L1 is on one side of the diagonal and each point in L2 is in the other side of the diagonal the, the diagonal lies completely inside the polygon. Now if any vertex in either list is on the other side of the diagonal as compared to other points in the same list , we say the diagonal is partially inside and partially outside the polygon .

Comment: For diagonal to lie completely outside the polygon ,all the points in both the lists should be on the same side:) We check the side using the equation of line I mentioned in the answer. Hope you understood it now:)

Comment: Added image in answer

Comment: Note that as mentioned in the comments by @High Performance Mark you have to give the list L 'in order' you join the vertices. Other wise you don't have a polygon and the logic won't work

Comment: Thank you very much, you did a great job!

Comment: In that case the code will become more lengthy and complex. You will have to then consider the diagonal as a line segment ,not a line i.e., for the diagonal joining the vertices on the inner side of the polygon.

Comment: Also , you will have to consider the diagonal if passes through more than two vertices of the polygon and other related cases. For example The condition for diagonal to completely lie inside will be same but you will have to treat it as a segment

Comment: Btw ,where are you using this in python,in which module are you working? This information can be of use to solve the problem

Comment: Thanks, I use matplotlib.pyplot but if i take it as a line segment i would need to reshape my polygon or?

Comment: I mean you have to consider the region perpendicular to the line segment and consider points in that region only. All the other points (vertices) will not be considered in the algorithm. Seems a bit difficult to apply but till now this is what has come to my mind:)